# Peripheral Interface Controller (PIC) using PHP language

Tags: php

Can I program the Peripheral Interface Controller (PIC) using PHP language?
I searched many websites and they didn't mention any clues. I hope someone here can help me.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? There are other better ways.

Comment: The meaning of other ways is Other Programming Language?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, depending on what you understand by "using" PHP.

If you want to use stock PHP installation, then no, there is no such way. However, you can create your own PHP extension in for example C language. This way, you can import anything the underlying system offers into PHP.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question,i think i gonna learn PHP extension now..i really appreciate both of u..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. The PHP interpreter would be too heavy weight for the limitations of a PIC processor.

You could convert your PHP to c/c++ with something like HipHop, but your PHP code would not be able to access any of the registers or input/output pins.

Now the long answer is that you could create a PHP extension to support the PIC and then cross-compile that to the PIC. That would be a pretty cool project.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question,i think i gonna learn PHP extension now..i really appreciate both of u..thanks.

Comment: @Erik Nedwidek: I played around some with HipHop and the resulting binary is 50+ MiB. Way to much.